# How to build g2o with CHOLMOD using android ndk?

Tags: android

as title says, I want to compile g2o with CHOLMOD using android ndk, but I found the dependency lib "cholmod" can not be compiled by android ndk, so my  g2o can not build too.Do someone have idea for this question?

Comment: Please provide some more information about the context of your problem. Include some error logs and information about the build tools you are using!